# ProGuard not obfuscating most of the code

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

We are having an issue that the proguard is not obfuscating most of the code except some local variables and some methods. Rest all the  method names (including private) remains as it - unobfuscated. I tried to look into previous posts with similar issues  and the most suggestions have to do with debuggable or -keep which is not applicable in this case as I explained below. Must be a silly mistake but we are not able to spot.

Below is a small part of mapping.txt shows proguard kept names as it

```
230:710:void onCreate(android.os.Bundle) -> onCreate
713:729:void setProfilePicture() -> setProfilePicture
733:737:void onStart() -> onStart
743:748:void createLocationRequest() -> createLocationRequest
755:759:void buildGoogleApiClient() -> buildGoogleApiClient
767:781:boolean checkPlayServices() -> checkPlayServices
787:794:void displayPlacePicker() -> displayPlacePicker
```

below is a relavant part of gradle file, as you can see, debuggable is false and minifyEnabled is true

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-library.pro'
        }
    }
```

Below is proguarf file, as you can see only two classes are kept CargoUI and CargoUIListener. However, it keeps methods from other classes (some are Activity/Fragment classes) as it without obfuscation.

```
-optimizationpasses 2
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-dontshrink
#-keepparameternames
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
#-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable,Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature
-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,SourceFile,LineNumberTable,*Annotation*,EnclosingMethod
-optimizations !field/removal/writeonly,!field/marking/private,!class/merging/*,!code/allocation/variable,!code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*
-dump dump.txt
-printmapping mapping.txt

-keep class butterknife.** { *; }
-dontwarn butterknife.internal.**
-keep class **$$ViewBinder { *; }

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    @butterknife.* <fields>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    @butterknife.* <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames,includedescriptorclasses class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keep class com.cargo.CargoUI {
    public static *;
    public *** init(...);
}

-keep class com.cargo.CargoUIListener {*;}

-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** w(...);
    public static *** v(...);
    public static *** i(...);
    public static *** e(...);
}

-assumenosideeffects class com.cargo.api.TMLog {
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** w(...);
    public static *** v(...);
    public static *** i(...);
    public static *** e(...);
}

-assumenosideeffects class com.cargo.api.Log {
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** w(...);
    public static *** v(...);
    public static *** i(...);
    public static *** e(...);
}


-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }

-keep class com.google.i18n.phonenumbers.** { *; }

##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature

# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }

##---------------End: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
```